# The context of callbacks is unclear

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

So, I created an http server in node to which I passed a callback that increments a global variable 'reqCounter', but I don't understand how it is incrementing it, how does createServer have access to 'reqCounter' isn't it defined somewhere else?

```
let reqCounter = 0;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end('Server has been accessed');
    reqCounter++;
    console.log('Incoming request' + ` ${reqCounter}`);
});
```

Isn't the context that createServer is defined in different from where reqCounter is defined?

Comment: The variable and the function are both inside whatever context they're in. What you're saying would be true if the variable were defined in some other block context.

Comment: it wouldn't have worked if 'a' wasn't a callback and we just incremented counter inside incrementCounter, how is it different for callbacks?

Comment: Sorry, but you can’t just edit the question into a _completely different_ one. Ask a new question instead. CC @bereal